# preserve timestamp on file inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Is there a `preserve-timestamp` property in the `file:inbound-channel-adapter` like in the `ftp:inbound-channel-adapter` or `sftp:inbound-channel-adapter`?
I have a requirement to copy some files from one folder to another folder (not FTP) and I need to keep the timestamp. 
If there isn't such property, can anyone suggest me how to this with spring integration?
For information, I'm using `spring-integration 3.0.8.RELEASE`. 
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The payload of the message from the file adapter is a `java.io.File`. If you want to move it to some other directory on the same physical disk, you could use a simple `<service-activator ... expression="payload.renameTo(...)" />`.

If you are using the file outbound channel adapter to copy the file to another disk, there is (currently) no option to preserve the timestamp.

I have opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3960) to add it as a new feature.

In the meantime; you could save off the `lastModified` in a header (using a header enricher) make the last channel before the outbound adapter a pub/sub channel, and add a second subscriber to set the `lastModified` on the new file.

Comment: thanks a lot Gary, for now I think I will use the header enricher to send the 'lastModified' property.